# Feature scaling with categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, k-nearest-neighbour, feature-scaling

I've a dataset with numeric features and categorical features. For the latter I created dummy variables.

I've to implement a KNN model so I've to scale my variables. My doubt is: how to handle these new dummies variables in the scaling operation? I've to scale all the variables (dummies and dummies) or only the numeric ones?

Comment: If you scale in this context, you usually normalize. And the dummies are already normalized.